# Merge tuple and integral instances into tuple of references

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++14, template-meta-programming

I've encountered strange behavior when trying to construct a tuple of references from a mix of tuples and integral values.

Given the following:

```
struct A { int v = 1; };
struct B { int v = 2; };
struct C { int v = 3; };
A a;
std::tuple<B,C> tpl;
```

I'm trying to create a third tuple which holds references to all instances, so that each instance's `v` will be assignable and readable through it.

Seems simple enough using templates

```
template <class Tuple, size_t... Is>
constexpr auto as_ref_impl(Tuple t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::tuple_cat(std::tie(std::get<Is>(t))...);
    // or
    // return std::make_tuple(std::ref(std::get<Is>(t))...);
}

template <class...Args>
constexpr auto as_ref(std::tuple<Args...>& t) {
    return as_ref_impl(t, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}
```

and then

```
auto ref_tpl = std::tuple_cat(std::tie(a), as_ref(tpl));
```

which builds fine (in both versions).

Unfortunately only the parts of the reference tuple (`ref_tpl`), which originate from integral values, can be assigned or read from successfully.

I'm using `C++14` and `gcc 9.3.0`.

Any ideas, or insight why this does not work, are very welcome!

**Minimal working example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

struct A { int v = 1; };
struct B { int v = 2; };
struct C { int v = 3; };
A a;
std::tuple<B,C> tpl;

template <class Tuple, size_t... Is>
constexpr auto as_ref_impl(Tuple t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    //return std::tuple_cat(std::tie(std::get<Is>(t))...);
    return std::make_tuple(std::ref(std::get<Is>(t))...);
}

template <class...Args>
constexpr auto as_ref(std::tuple<Args...>& t) {
    return as_ref_impl(t, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}

int main() {
    using std::cout;

    auto ref_tpl = std::tuple_cat(std::tie(a), as_ref(tpl));

    // prints 1 2 3, as expected.
    cout << a.v << std::get<0>(tpl).v << std::get<1>(tpl).v << std::endl;

    std::get<0>(ref_tpl).v = 8; // works
    std::get<1>(ref_tpl).v = 9; // does not work
    std::get<2>(ref_tpl).v = 10; // does not work

    // should output 8 9 10 instead outputs 8 2 3
    cout << a.v << std::get<0>(tpl).v << std::get<1>(tpl).v << std::endl;

    // should output 8 9 10, instead outputs garbage.
    cout << std::get<0>(ref_tpl).v << std::get<1>(ref_tpl).v << std::get<2>(ref_tpl).v << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple typo:

`constexpr auto as_ref_impl(Tuple t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {`

`Tuple` is taken by value, so a local copy is made, and the reference is made relative to it.

You should take `Tuple` by reference instead,

`constexpr auto as_ref_impl(Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {`

Comment: Haha welp, thanks. Can't believe I just spent a full hour on this!

Answer (score 1):

Your `as_ref_impl` needs to take the `Tuple` parameter by reference, otherwise you are taking a `std::ref` to a function local. This explains the unmodified values of `tpl`, and the garbage values in `ref_tpl`.

Do this instead:

```
template <class Tuple, size_t... Is>
// note the reference parameter
constexpr auto as_ref_impl(Tuple &t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {      
    return std::make_tuple(std::ref(std::get<Is>(t))...);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/XARnBn).